# How to build/package/distribute Java console application so it can be run by double-clicking it in Applications folder on Mac

Tags: java, macos, jpackage

I packaged a Java console application using `jpackage`. I can install the app and also run it from the command-line by giving the full path of the executable like:

```
/Applications/my-app.app/Contents/MacOS/my-app
```

But when I double-click the app in the Applications folder nothing happens (not even an error). Similarly if I try to launch it from Spotlight, nothing happens.

What can I do so that I can run the application:

- by double-clicking on it in the Applications folder?
- by typing its name in Spotlight?

I am using:

- JDK21
- Mac OS Ventura

Providing some more details: Related Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100218/macos-app-launcher-built-by-jpackage-not-completing-launch). I tried the suggested answer:

> In the MacOS folder, right-click on the Terminal icon showing your app's name. Open with Terminal....

> This will show you any errors fired during the launch sequence.

*In my case there are no errors if I try to run the application using the steps above. It launches normally. In fact, I can launch it by double-clicking on it in the MacOS folder.*

I also inspected `Utilities->Console` in Mac and saw following messages (when I attempt to launch the app by double-clicking on it):

```
Checking PreventLaunch: global:0 exPath:/Applications/xxx.app/Contents/MacOS/xxx predicates:(null) allow:(null)
-[PersistentAppsSupport applicationReady:] | App: xxx, ready, updating active tracking timer
-[ApplicationManager checkInAppContext:eventData:] | ApplicationManager: Checked in app : xxx
-[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | for app:xxx, _appTrackingState = 2
-[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | App: xxx, quit, updating active tracking timer
```

I also tried the steps [here](https://centerkey.com/mac/java/) with the difference that I created a console app instead of a GUI application and got the same result. You cannot launch the app by double-clicking on it in the `Applications` folder. Double-clicking the binary under `Contents/MacOS` works as earlier.

I have also tried opening the app using:

```
open /Applications/my-app.app
```

on the command-line. This gives same result as double-clicking the app in `Applications` folder (does not launch). No output is logged to the command-line.